# ArcGIS - Centeralizing location

Tags: flash, apache-flex, arcgis, flash-builder

All,

I'm using ArcGIS component for showing maps. I would like to make the given location to be displayed at the center of my browser page. I have left/top side navigation bars and the rest of the space is occupied by ArcGIS map component.

Can anyone help me on this

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've named your map "map":

```
map.extent = map.extent.centerAt(new MapPoint(myX, myY));
```

Note that centerAt() doesn't change the map extent, it creates a new one, and you can set the map's extent to that.

EDIT:

This is more complicated, but it'll find the real center of the control you pass in for you:

```
        public function centerAtXY(relativeTo:DisplayObject, x:Number, y:Number):void
        {
            //Get the center of the displayobject's position on the map
            var offsetPoint:MapPoint = map.toMapFromStage(relativeTo.width /2, relativeTo.height /2);

            //Find the distance between the map's center and the display's center in map units
            var offsetX:Number = map.extent.center.x - offsetPoint.x;
            var offsetY:Number = map.extent.center.y - offsetPoint.y;

            //Recenter the map so x,y is at the center of the displayobject
            var centerPoint:MapPoint = new MapPoint(x + offsetX, y + offsetY);
            map.extent = map.extent.centerAt(centerPoint);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dan, Even I have coded like the same way you suggested, But for some reasons it is not working.. I have left and top navigation bars as well

Comment: @DavidR Is the issue that you're trying to put it in the exact center of the window, not the center of the map control?

Comment: Well. I need to place it in the exact center of my BorderLayout. Can you help me on this?

Comment: You'll need to position it down and to the right of your central point.

Comment: Extremely sorry.. Can you post an example if possible?